# Plotting multiple geom_lines at the same time and shift them on the X axis in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has individual records with ZIP Codes and Installation Dates. So far, I was able to plot records in a ZIP Code by:

- Subset a ZIP Code
- Sort the records by Date
- Create a new column and assign increasing values (by 1) for the next row.
- Plot this last field by Date

The result looks like this:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is have multiple ZIP Code geom_lines in the same figure. Each ZIP Code area has a different first record date, and I would like all of them to start at the same point on the X-axis.

Here's a failed attempt. I want these lines to start at the same point on the X-axis:

[image]

I am looking for ideas on how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to make your question reproducible and thus answerable, we need minimal, self-contained code and data so that we are able to reproduce your problem on our machine, please follow these guidelines: [mre], https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to roughly emulate your data structure since your question does not include any data:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(
  ZIP   = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 687)),
  Count = c(cumsum(round(runif(1000, 0, 0:999))), 
            cumsum(round(runif(687, 0, 0:686) * 4))),
  Date = c(seq(as.POSIXct("2007-09-01"), by = "1 week", length.out = 1000),
           seq(as.POSIXct("2013-08-31"), by = "1 week", length.out = 687)))
   
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Count, colour = ZIP)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Now clearly, if we want these lines to start at the same position on the x axis, the x axis can no longer reflect the absolute date, but rather the *time since the first record*. So we need to calculate what this would be for each group. The dplyr package can help us here:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ZIP) %>% 
  mutate(Day = as.numeric(difftime(Date, min(Date), units = "days"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Day, Count, colour = ZIP)) + 
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Day since first record") +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]